# Privileges shows different votes

Tags: bug, reputation

In the Achievements list [one answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41218986) it shows 61 marks. I clicked that in the list, and it shows four upvotes and one accepted answer on the answer page (totally 55 marks). Why this difference happen?

I attached both screen shots:

[image]

[image]

Comment: do you have a +10 notification before that?

Answer (score 6):

Because you actually have 6 up votes and 2 down votes

[image]

So you have (6 * 10) + (2 * -2) + 15 = 71

Comment: But it's showing 61, not 71

Comment: and its -3 now..

Comment: @Floern The votes are still coming in so they may have received more in the time between question asked and my answer was posted.

Comment: The last upvote was [cast on Apr 18](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/41218986/timeline), so it should take all 6 upvotes into account in the achievements list. The only reason that it may be not here is that the latest upvote is listed separately in the "last 30 days" section, but that would be somewhat off..

Comment: Unless it includes all 30 days *before* the "last 7 days", then it would make sense.

Comment: Well look at that.  I didn't see how old it was.  Guess we need to see more.  Should I delete?

Comment: @NathanOliver,Where is located it get 6 upvotes and 2 down votes.

Comment: @Mansoor https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user click on the number between up and down arrow